# Network profile badges not counting rightly anymore, apparently

Tags: bug, badges, combined-flair

I'm aware of the documentation badges in SO issue, I lost 3 of them so this isnt about this. My network profile shows a drop in another 61 bronze badges depending where you see it (264 to 205), and if you count them manually they still add the former figure (264). So what's this about, am I going to see a disappearence in my other communities bronze badges soon so that's why they still add up to 264, or it's a bug in the badges counter? [image]

Comment: in which SE site did you see the 205 bronze badges? I checked several of your SE sites and in all of them I saw the 264 bronze badges.

Comment: @Yaron it's sum of all badges from all sites where user has at least 200 reputation.

Comment: Anyway, it's a long time bug that was never fixed. Most people simply never notice it.

Comment: here I see 205 but it always showed 264 . It just changed yesterday or the day before yesterday https://stackexchange.com/users/67408/pablo